# Capturing the read line with FlatFileItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm reading a csv file with `FlatFileItemReader` and using a `FieldSetMapper` to map it to a domain object.

In case the mapping fails, I would like to have the original line read by the `FlatFileItemReader` at my disposal so I could write it to another csv file.

My original idea was to use some listener to push the read string to `StepContext` and then a `SkipListener` to fetch the string to write it to another file. But I can't find a way to catch the original line read by the `FlatFileItemReader`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your configuration is similar to the [Spring Batch Documentation for FlatFileItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html), you could use a custom LineMapper instead of the usual [DefaultLineMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/DefaultLineMapper.html) which throws an enriched exception

here is some simple example code

```
public class DefaultLineMapper<T> implements LineMapper<T>, InitializingBean {
    (...)

public T mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
            try {
      return fieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(tokenizer.tokenize(line));
            }
            catch (...) {
                throw new CustomException(line, lineNumber);
            }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Implementing the onReadError(Exception) method of the [ItemReadListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemReadListener.html) interface  does exactly what you need.

```
public void onReadError(Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof FlatFileParseException) {
        FlatFileParseException ffpe = (FlatFileParseException) e;
        ffpe.getLineNumber(); //The line number error occured
        ffpe.getInput();//Text value of the unparsed line
    }
}
```